# Is this piecewise function differentiable at zero?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: The question]

I know that $\frac{\sin^2 x}x$ has a hole at $x=0$. I can take the limit from the left and right of zero, but the $x=0$ function is confusing me.

Comment: That's two different answers. I know that zero is a constant so it's derivative is zero, which is correct. But that tangent line is very different from the sin function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: EDIT: I made a stupid mistake: It is differentiable and $f'(0)=1$

Comment: @MicahWindsor Maybe this is miscommunication: I am talking about the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{\sin^2(x)}x, & x\neq 0\\0, &x=0\end{cases}$$ defined on all of $\mathbb R$. Then $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)-0}h=1.$$ Also what is the difference between $x$ and $0$ if $x=0$ ?

Comment: @MicahWindsor You are confusing two things: There is no difference between $0$ and $x$ at the *singleton* $x=0$ (which is the case above), but there is a difference if you consider $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x$ on some neighborhood of $0$. But $f(0)=0$ is a statement about a singleton, not about an open neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I have now posted the bug you discovered here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219273/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$LHD  f'(0^-)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(-h)-f(0)}{-h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{sin^2(-h)}{-h}-0}{-h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{sin^2(h)}{h^2}=1$$

$$RHD  f'(0^+)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{sin^2(h)}{h}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{sin^2(h)}{h^2}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

I'll start you off: $f(x)$ is differentiable at zero.

The function $g(x)=\frac{sin^2(x)}{x}$ has a hole at zero, as you observed. However, the function defined in your problem (it's called $f(x)$) is very similar to $g(x)$ except that it has that hole at $x=0$ filled in - so your function is nice and smooth with no jumps, holes, edges, etc.

We can see that the limit as x goes to $0$ from either side is $0$ AND the value at $x=0$ is also $0$. Now your problem wants you to use the definition of the derivative to *prove* that it's differentiable. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I submitted, and received full credit for. Thought I would share in case anyone runs into a similar problem in the future.

[image: Solved Problem]