# How does $\frac{df_1}{dx}$ convert to $2xy$ when $f_1(x,y) = x^2 \cdot y$

Tags: calculus, determinant, jacobian

I was looking at the first example on Wikipedia here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_1

The first item in the Jacobian Matrix, according to the example, converts to $2xy$. Can someone explain to me how that's the case?

[image]

Comment: I think this is just partial differentiate wrt $x$.

Comment: **JustWandering** gave a correct answer/hint. Why you are confused about that result?

Comment: I don't understand where the 2 comes from in the differentiate. If x^2/x = x, then how is it that (x^2 * y)/x would equal 2xy. The rest of the differentiates make sense to me, but for some reason, not this one

Comment: What is the derivative of $x^2$ ? Is it $x$? No, it is $2x$.

Comment: If you are new to partial differentiation, all you have to do is hold anything other than $x$ as a constant, loosely speaking. If you new to differentiation then you have to look it up to get a sense of this topic.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch While you probably could have phrased that more kindly, your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks. It's been over 20 years since I've done any calculus, and I'm trying to refresh my memory.

Comment: Hi @DavidMorton, I didn’t mean to be rude, I may have been a bit impatient because I had a [four hour long discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3619260/631742) about the derivative of a function on this site yesterday  (most of the conversation has been deleted now, originally there were 18 comments)